# TextViews are on top of each other - Android XML

Tags: android, xml, textview

I just started to learn Android Development (with Android Studio), but I have some trouble.
The TextViews on the activity_main.xml are placed on top of each other, instead of under each other.

I just copied the default TextView and change the text to another string.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/matttest" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

How can I make sure that the TextViews are placed under each other, instead of on top of each other?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id= "@+id/textview1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id= "@+id/textview2" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"  
        android:text="@string/matttest" />
```

Use the layout below,above to place the views relative to each other

Comment: I have to wait a bit. I'm not allowed to accept something as an answer for another 3 minutes